# How to make VScode Go work in a Multi-Module Repo

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a go.mod file in a golang project, and I also have another go project which is embedded in this project, but vscode does not seem to recognize this embedded project. Is there a way to work with multiple golang project with vscode?

Comment: not sure that vscode is happy with this kind of thing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add the modules directory to your workspace using the "file / add folder to work space" menu.

Answer (score 5):

Be careful when using go.work which others suggest.

Just adding go.work and adding all modules to `use` will cause all your modules use the same dependencies, which might not be what you want. Especially if you want to have different versions of dependencies at different submodules.

It’s fine if you don’t care about that, but if you do, VSCode does not support multiple modules currently.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a multi-module workspace and this is supported by Go and VSCode. If you are using Go 1.17 and earlier then fix is a configuration option on VSCode (experimentalWorkspaceModule setting). If you have Go 1.18+ then fix is using the new go.work file.

Check this article for more details https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md

Comment: This is actually a bit dangerous advice. go.work changes semantics of module selection; it will use different set of dependencies with and without it. It can make hard to find bugs.